# I need help with this geometry question.

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $AB=AC$. If $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$, $E$ is the foot of the perpendicular drawn from $D$ to $AC$ and $F$ the mid-point of $DE$, prove that $AF$ is perpendicular to $BE$.
>   (JEE-1989)

[image: Figure]

I have solved it using coordinate geometry (or rather truthfully, seen the solution), but was wondering if it could be solved by geometry.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is “JEE-1989”? Can you spell that out and/or add a link? I've found several copies of this question on the web, but non in a book matching these initials. When you say “by geometry”, does that include trigonometry?

Comment: JEE stands for Joint Engineering Examination and 1989 is the year of the paper. It is a rather difficult competitive examination in which this question appeared and has no real relevance to the question. And i have no objections to you using trignometry. I just wanted to know if it was possible to solve it without using coordinate geometry.

Comment: I'm trying to create a site for "Indian Competitive Exams" and your question seems to be related to it, I think you would be interested to support it [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86609/indian-competitive-exams?referrer=uQtcXaMCGQOGlwjYmelKJA2) and spread the word to your friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BD$.  Drop a perpendicular from $D$ to $AM$, meeting it at $P$.  Drop a perpendicular from $D$ to $AB$, meeting it at $H$.

[image: diagram]

**Part 1:** $BPE$ are collinear.

Since
$$ \frac{AP}{PM} = \frac{AP}{PD}\cdot\frac{PD}{PM}
= \left(\frac{AD}{DM}\right)^2 $$
and similarly $\frac{CE}{EA} = \left(\frac{CD}{AD}\right)^2$, we have
$$ \frac{AP}{PM}\cdot\frac{MB}{BC}\cdot\frac{CE}{EA}
= \left(\frac{AD}{DM}\right)^2 \left(-\frac14\right) \left(\frac{CD}{AD}\right)^2
= \left(\frac{CD}{DM}\right)^2 \left(-\frac14\right) = -1
$$
Thus $BPE$ are collinear by Menelaus' theorem.

**Part 2:** $\angle DPE = \angle BAD$.

Since $DP\perp PA$ and $DH\perp HA$, by Thales' theorem $DPHA$ are concyclic, as shown.  Therefore $\angle PHD = \angle PAD$, since they stand on the same arc $PD$.  Now, since $\angle PHB = \frac\pi2-\angle PHD$, and $\angle PMB = \pi-\angle PMD = \pi-(\frac\pi2-\angle PAD)$, it follows that $\angle PHB+\angle PMB = \pi$, and so $BMPH$ are concyclic, as shown.  Next, since $BH\perp HD$ and $M$ is the midpoint of $BD$, we have $MH=MB$; therefore $\angle MBH$ and $\angle BPM$ stand on equal arcs, and so they are equal angles.  Finally,
$$ \angle DPE = \tfrac\pi2 - \angle BPM = \tfrac\pi2-\angle MBH = \angle BAD $$

**Part 3:** $AF\perp BE$.

Apply the similarity transformation taking $\triangle ABD$ to $\triangle ADE$, that is, rotating about $A$ by $\angle BAD$ and then scaling by $\frac{AD}{AB}$.  This map sends $D$ to $E$ and sends the median $AM$ to the median $AF$.  Since we rotate by $\angle BAD = \angle DPE$, it sends the line $DP$ to a line parallel to $EB$, so it must send the line $DP$ to the line $EB$.  Since $DP\perp AM$ by construction, this shows that $EB\perp AF$.

**Remark:** If we consider $A$ and $B$ to be fixed and let $C$ vary on a circle, the locus of point $E$ is a cardioid.  Maybe some short proof is possible using the properties of cardioid...

Comment: A much simpler solution is in K.D. Joshi's book *Educative JEE Mathematics*, on [Google books](http://books.google.ca/books?id=MtbtL-c0N4wC&pg=PA270#v=onepage) (see under "Comment No. 9").